# League email for Home Improvement has bad link

Tags: bug, status-completed

I just got an email saying that I am one of the **top new Home Improvement - Stack Exchange users for the week of Apr 18 2011!** (emphisis *yours*). Well, wasn't I excited!! So, I clicked on the link in the email.

- http://stackexchange.com/leagues/week/diy/2011-04-18

and it promptly took me to a lovely 404 page (something about pandas off to my right!?)

After a little looking around, I found that the link should have been...

- http://stackexchange.com/leagues/23/week/diy/2011-04-17

Then, after all of that excitement, I couldn't even find myself on the list!

Thanks,

Jim

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That link is no longer a dead link.

There's a wrinkle to this though, in that the StackExchange.com leagues only show users with >= 200 rep.  We've amended these e-mails to explain that, and to also link to the site's `/users` page (which shows running totals for the current week/month/quarter/year).